# How to detect touch on sprite or texture in libGDX java?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, sprite

I have a home button icon which is just a normal sprite with an image in it. 
I want to perform some actions on the touch of this button. How can I add touch listener to this button or is there any other simpler way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LibGdx, How to handle touch event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35287866/libgdx-how-to-handle-touch-event)

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501268/how-do-i-detect-if-a-sprite-was-touched-in-java-libgdx or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24834399/how-to-detect-if-a-texture-has-been-touched-libgdx-without-scene2d

Comment: What's about an ImageButton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this, is to set a `Rectangle` with the button bounds of your button.

```
Rectangle buttonBounds = new Rectangle(buttonX, buttonY, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
```

If you then want to check if the user touched the button, in your `render()` method, put:

```
if(Gdx.input.justTouched()){
    Vector2 touch = viewport.unproject(new Vector2(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY()));

    //Check if button if touched
    if(buttonBounds.contains(touch)){
        System.out.println("Button touched!");
        //Do something
    }
}
```

If you don't use a `Viewport`, you can change `viewport.unproject()` to `cam.unproject()`, where `cam` is your `Camera`.